# pymongo - "OperationFailure: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field"

Tags: python, pymongo

I want to randomly sample a given number of document for which the field 'date' is greater or equal to '2020-01-01'. Here is  my code

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


client = MongoClient('connection sting')
db = client.myDataBase

pipeline = [{'$sample':{'size': numberOfDocument}, 'date':{'$gte':'2020:01:01'}}]
pd.DataFrame(list(db['collectionName'].aggregate(pipeline)))
```

The last line gives me the following error

Does someone know how to get the write result?
    OperationFailure: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.

Comment: The error is telling you that you cannot specify the date selection as part of the `$sample` stage. Have you tried the date selection as a `$match` stage prior to the `$sample`?

Comment: Well I hadn't. I just tried it by changing the pipeline by [{'$match': {'date':{'$gte':'2020:01:01'}}}, {'$sample':{'size': 2}}]  and it gave me " _ "

Comment: Ok I figured the problem out. I used ":" instead of "-". The right pipeline is [{'$match': {'date':{'$gte':'2020-01-01'}}}, {'$sample':{'size': 2}}] and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pymongo you need to use datetime objects. You'll need to import datetime.

Please try:

```py
date_match = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)

pipline = [{'$match': {'date': {'$gte': date_match}}},
           {'$sample': {'size': 2}}]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this way to do it. I also replied to your other comment.